# convert openssl_private_encrypt output to hex php

Tags: php, openssl, hex

I have an encrypted message from the openssl_private_encrypt methode. But I need it in 32 bit hex. How can I convert it? Can someone tell me witch format it the encrypted message has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run the resulting string through base64_encode(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php